# Lua read json file

Tags: json, lua

I am trying to read json file in lua , with below code (test.lua). But when I run this code , I dont get any output , script just hangs . I am not understanding where I am going wrong

```lua
json = require("json") 
f = io.open(path, "r")
io.input(f)
local content = io.read("*a")
io.close()
config = json.decode(content)
for key, value in pairs(config) do print(key, value) end
```

note :- I have placed json.lua in the same folder where I am creating this test.lua

Comment: Why was this tagged [tag:c++]?

Comment: removed , but mostly c++ ppl know lua , so i guess it makes sense

Comment: But it's not c++ related. Anyways, please perform basic debugging, where does it hang exactly?

Comment: `io.close()` closes your default stdout.  So yes, it "hangs".

Comment: @ESkri yes it does and that's definitely a bug, but still the `print` won't hang. What's more plausible is that `f` is `nil` (e.g. wrong path), thus `io.input()` is a no-op returning the current file name. `io.read"*a"` will then block until the program gets EOF on stdin.

Answer (score 1):

Let's rewrite your code:

```lua
local json = require("json")
local f = assert(io.open(path, "r")) -- assuming path is in the scope
local content = f:read("*a")
f:close()
local config = json.decode(content)
for key, value in pairs(config) do print(key, value) end
```

as of 5.4, you can save yourself the `:close()` and replace it with a more robust `<close>` (which will also be triggered if the variable goes out of scope in case of an error):

```
local f <close> = assert(io.open(path, "r"))
```

This eliminates a bug (unspecified behavior) that could be responsible for your hang: If opening the file fails (e.g. file not found or missing permissions), then `io.input(nil)` will be a no-op returning the current stdin, but not changing it. Thus you will be waiting for end-of-file on stdin when trying to read all of it using `io.read("*a")`.

It also eliminates a second bug pointed out by ESkri in the comments: The call `io.close()` closes your stdout. It does not close your stdin. The file remains open.

To properly error out, wrap the call to `io.open` in an assertion.

It is extremely bad practice to tamper with the global stdin or stdout unless necessary. (Ab)using stdin & stdout for file I/O rather than directly using file handles is a massive code smell and isn't even more concise.